# ASUS Q302 Smart Gesture Touchpad not detected 14.04

Tags: touchpad

I have a ASUS Q302LA laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 installed.  Touchpad isn't detected.  What driver do I need to install to get the Asus smart gesture touchpad working?  I am not for sure of the manufacturer of the touchpad, when I try the xinput command it only shows the PS/2 mouse - logitech.